# Прокрутка внутри элемента при помощи CSS

Tags: html, css

Есть dropdown кнопка , и при клике на эту кнопку выходит доп. меню рядом. В эту менюшку вывожу данные из базы таким образом и сам код кнопки выглядит так.

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">65 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <?php  $result65z = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM forma43")  or die(mysqli_error());?>
            <?php while($row65z = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result65z )) { ?>         
                <li>
                    <a href="043reg.php?card_id=<?php echo $cardid ?>&zubnum=65&diag=<?php echo $row65z['kod'];  ?>"><?php echo $row65z['naimenovanie'];  ?> - <?php echo $row65z['kod'];  ?></a>
                </li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Данные из базы выводятся нормально, но так как в базе данных много рядом с кнопкой выходит длинная (18 строк) и неудобная менюшка. Хотелось бы как то сократить эту менюшку. Показывать например только 5-6 строк а дальше поставить прокрутку внутри элемента. Как это можно сделать ? Спасибо за любые ответы идеи и предложения !

PS да и ещё прошу прощения за "некрасивый" код )

Comment: Добавить max-height на 5-6 строк, и добавить overflow-y: auto

Comment: Спасибо Вам , если честно не знал как это сделать, Shnur обьяснил !) От души благодарен и Вам

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
.dropdown-menu {
   max-height: 100px;
   overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое, Shnur. Вы мне очень помогли !